# ipad/iphone disable exit button

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

Can we disable the exit button of ipad/iphone .Basically i don't want the application to be submitted to apple store and want to  functionality as like as soon as the app open user cannot close that app , means i need to disable the exit button present at bottom of our iphone /ipad.

The basic reason behonf this is as soon a the app opens up user cannot close the app , he needs to restart the iphone /ipad .

Hope i am clear with my question .Any suggestions are welcomed.

Regards
Mrugen

Comment: Sounds like a terrible application, but who am I to judge, MobileSubstrate offers hooks at a SpringBoard level but do not know how much that will help you http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable the home button, it's impossible with the APIs that Apple provides. If you're willing to stray into jailbreak territory, you could use MobileSubstrate to power your application.

Instead, show a message on launch that warns the user to reboot.